# Настройка модульного тестирования php

Tags: юнит-тесты, php

В статье http://habrahabr.ru/post/56289/ есть пример

```
   require_once 'PHPUnit/Framework.php';
   require_once 'MyClass.php';

class MyClassTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
public function testPower()
{
    $my = new MyClass();
    $this->assertEquals(8, $my->power(2, 3)); 
 }
}
```

После установки phpunit файл framework.php отсутствует. Где его найти?
Имеется файл только Autoload.php.
Пробую подключить его

```
require_once '../usr/local/php5/pear/PEAR/PHPUnit-3.7.13/PHPUnit/Autoload.php';
require_once 'myClass.php';
Warning: require_once(../usr/local/php5/pear/PEAR/PHPUnit-3.7.13/PHPUnit/Autoload.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Y:\home\unotTest\www\MyClassTest.php on line 3

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '../usr/local/php5/pear/PEAR/PHPUnit-3.7.13/PHPUnit/Autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php5/pear/') in Y:\home\unotTest\www\MyClassTest.php on line 3
```

Comment: http://pear.phpunit.de/

Comment: Отсюда и качал последнюю версию

Comment: КАК РЕШИТЬ?

Comment: http://fkn.ktu10.com/?q=node/494

Кому пригодится. После установки phpunit дополните его файлами из ссылки выше.